# Bizzare MPI output

Tags: c, mpi

I'm a novice in MPI programming and now I'm playing with sample programs to study the basics of MPI I/O.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define BUFSIZE 10

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int myrank, size;
    MPI_File thefile;
    int i;
    int buf[BUFSIZE];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    for (i=0; i<BUFSIZE; i++)
            buf[i] = myrank * BUFSIZE + i;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "testfile",
                  MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
                  MPI_INFO_NULL, &thefile);
    MPI_File_set_view(thefile, myrank * BUFSIZE * sizeof(int),
                      MPI_INT, MPI_INT, "native",
                      MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_write(thefile, buf, BUFSIZE, MPI_INT,
                   MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_File_close(&thefile);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
```

}

And this is an output:

```
^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^E^@^@^@^F^@^@^@^G^@^@^@^H^@^@^@        ^@^@^@
^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^L^@^@^@^M^@^@^@^N^@^@^@^O^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^Q^@^@^@^R^@^@^@^S^@^@^@
```

The compiler I use is mpich2 on Scientific Linux SL release 6.0. I also tried it on Ubuntu 14.04 and the answer is the same. Do you have any ideas what happens?

Comment: You're not specifying what you're expecting! Also, a textual representation of a binary file isn't very useful for debugging.

Comment: You write each each integer as four bytes to the text file: 00 00 00 01, 00 00 00 02, ...

Comment: Yep, sorry.
So, for a case of 2 nodes I'm expecting something kind of
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

"Also, a textual representation of a binary file isn't very useful for debugging"

Actually, this is the essence of my question. I don't get why I don't obtain the file I expect.

Comment: I have no experience with MPI, but after a quick glance at the documentation of MPI_File_write() I would say that this function simply writes the (binary representation of the) given array to the file. There is no printf-like transformation from numbers to strings done.

Comment: Is there any possibility to get a conventional output using MPI?

Comment: "conventional" is a very stretchable word. I'd say that for integers, this is the most intuitive way of storage.

I don't know about any MPI that does string formatting (it's clearly not MPI's job to format strings for printing), so you'd probably do what every other C programmer would do: use `sprintf` or similar functions.

Answer (score 1):

The file is probably correct. What you're seeing is the raw integers, as they are in memory.

You're hence opening a binary file and hoping to see text there -- that's not going to happen.

Either, you will need something to convert integers (which are just bytes with the value they store in memory) to text (which is a sequence of bytes, where each byte represents a character, which in turn might represent something like a decimal digit).

Seriously, this is a very basic concept, and you should be a little more familiar with things like these, and writing C code in general, before tackling MPI, which really is thought for programmers who know pretty well how programs work on a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

The entire concept of MPI-IO is built upon **binary** data structures, so that each basic record in the file has the same size and it is trivial to compute the file offset of an arbitrary record. This is not the case with textual output. For example, if the work is split in half between two processes, you cannot write the second half of the file before you know how long the textual representation of the first half is going to be. This prevents writing both parts in parallel, which is what MPI-IO is for.

To alleviate it either:

- gather the information in one process and perform regular (POSIX) formatted I/O there

or

- use fixed width number fields e.g. something like `%10d` as format specifier while building intermediate character arrays, then use `MPI_CHAR` to as basic type for MPI-IO. Depending on the value range, this could potentially lead to lots of wasted space

or

- have each rank output to a separate file and then concatenate the files using a regular file paste mechanism, e.g. `cat output_0 output_1 output_2 ... > output`.

Comment: @user43283, if it really helped you resolve your problem, please mark the answer as accepted to help future users quickly identify it as such. Thanks!